# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from closing non-existent files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I change branch (git), VSCode closes files from workspace which doesn't exist in new branch. So when I change the branch back to the old one, I have to open all those files again.

I want the files to stay open, just marked as "Deleted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) consider using multiple git workspaces(sharing the .git folder) with multiple vscode windows, then you could not need to switch between branches at all

b) [image: make]
make sure Close FIles On Delete setting is off

c) try to use commandline git with b) if VSCode builtin fit still closes files